# Where i can find drupal 8 views module example?

Tags: php, api, drupal, module, view

Hello i'm a newbie in Drupal 8 and since the api does not have a fully explained example (source code) about views i want your feedback with a simple example or some links to make a start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want an example of? I have not yet played much with drupal 8, but I would expect views in drupal 8 to be similar to drupal 7 from a front end configuration point of view. If you are talking about writing views plugins etc. (you mention API so this may be the case), you would have to be more specific about what sort of views plugin/extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below links you can find examples for creating views in Drupal 8

> 1. https://www.drupal.org/node/1912118
> 2. http://www.webwash.net/drupal/tutorials/build-blog-drupal-8-using-views